# How to gett whois lookup result?

Tags: whois

So anyways, I'm working on a small PHP website/script, and as one of the features I'd like to be able to run a WHOIS lookup on the current domain the PHP script is running on.
I don't know much about WHOIS lookups (well, I know what they do, I just don't know how to run them in PHP)
Please let me know how to do it and get same result as : http://www.ipfingerprints.com/whois.php.

Comment: Did you do a search?  the first result for php whois should be http://www.phpwhois.org/

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Linux, you can simply call exec() with the Linux whois command.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_whois.htm
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

 If not, I'm sure there is a Windows cmdline alternative for whois.

Comment: No, this is the worse advice to give! Do not escape to the shell from PHP just to start a whois command, as this will create a bunch of security and performance problems. PHP has libraries to do whois queries so use them inside your language or if you prefer a low level just open a TCP socket to port 43 and read RFC3912 for the whois protocol specification.